# how to redirect using url parameter with slashes

Tags: php, redirect, joomla, header

I am trying to pass a URL parameter as follows:

```
myscript.php?video=some.site.com/vids/v1.wnv
```

I am using the following in my PHP file

```
// get url parameter for video selected
$jAp = JFactory::getApplication();  
$jInput = $jAp->input;
$video = $jInput->get('video');

header("Location: http://".$video
```

but when I echo out `$video` I get the following

```
some.site.comvidsv1.wmv
```

There is no `http://` in what is echoed out.

How can I do this?

Comment: no  $video is the php variable I am trying to use to get the URL from the link that a person selected on my site.  Each link calls my php script and as noted above I am trying to parse the URL assigned to the video parameter in the URL and then use header() to send the person to the new URL.  My PHP script monitors who selected what and updates a backend database, then does the redirect... the issue is, if the URL parameter has slashes in it, they get removed.

Answer (score 1):

With Joomla, you can add filters, such as `STIRNG`, `HTML` and so on.

Try the following:

```
$video = $jInput->get('video', '', 'RAW' );
```

Then you can use the following:

```
header("Location: " . $video);
```

For more information on `JInput`, have a read of the following:

http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput

Comment: this got the value of the video with the slashes... now there is no http:// even though I use header("Location: http://".$video);   I even tried header("Location: http://http://".$video);

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
header("Location: http://http://".$video);
```

Comment: when I do this I get http// followed by the correct path.  So how do I get the http:// to appear?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding you, where exactly do you want the http:// to appear?